# CuPy muti GPU cuFFT Support

Tags: cupy

May I know what is the official support with latest cupy version for cuFFT Multi GPU?

Is it:
step 1: Copy dat ato gpu --> f_gpu = cp.asarray(f) # move the data to the current device
step 2: Set number of GPU --> cp.fft.config.use_multi_gpus = True cp.fft.config.set_cufft_gpus(8)
step 3 Call FFT --> fk_gpu =  cp.fft.rfftn(f_gpu)/(Nx*Ny*Nz)

Is this the right approach? The documentation says it is experimental. And there are other methods being tested. I see only one gpu being used even though we set more number of GPU. In debugging I also see it set gpu returns tuple of 8 GPU which are present in system.

Answer (score 4):

Welcome to SO! I am one of the main drivers behind CuPy's FFT support these days, so I think I am obligated to reply here

CuPy's multi-GPU FFT support currently has two kinds. One is with high-level `cupy.fft.{fft, ifft}` API, which requires the input array to reside on one of the participating GPUs. The multi-GPU calculation is done under the hood, and by the end of the calculation the result again resides on where it started. It basically follows what you described, but only c2c transform is supported; c2r/r2c (such as `rfftn` in your example) is not, due to a potential bug in cuFFT.

```py
import cupy as cp

cp.fft.config.use_multi_gpus = True
cp.fft.config.set_cufft_gpus([0, 1])  # use GPU 0 & 1

shape = (64, 64)
dtype = cp.complex64
a = cp.random.random(shape).astype(dtype)  # reside on GPU 0

b = cp.fft.fft(a)  # computed on GPU 0 & 1, reside on GPU 0
```

If you need to do N-D transforms (ex: `fftn`) instead of 1D (ex: `fft`), it'd likely still work, but in this particular use case it loops over the transformed axes under the hood (which is exactly what's done in NumPy too), so I don't think it's optimal. In terms of API, probably it's better to turn `use_multi_gpus` into a context manager, I will think about it.

Another kind of usage is to use the low-level APIs. You need to construct a `Plan1d` object and use it as if you're programming in C/C++ with cuFFT. Note that using this in this way, your array can reside on CPU as a `numpy.ndarray`, so it can support a much larger input array than the previous case could (as there it was bound by the memory on a single GPU), which IMHO is really the main reason of using multi-GPU FFT.

```py
import numpy as np
import cupy as cp

# no need to touch cp.fft.config, as we are using low-level API

shape = (64, 64)
dtype = np.complex64
a = np.random.random(shape).astype(dtype)  # reside on CPU

if len(shape) == 1:
    batch = 1
    nx = shape[0]
elif len(shape) == 2:
    batch = shape[0]
    nx = shape[1]

# compute via cuFFT
cufft_type = cp.cuda.cufft.CUFFT_C2C  # single-precision c2c
plan = cp.cuda.cufft.Plan1d(nx, cufft_type, batch, devices=[0,1])
out_cp = np.empty_like(a)  # output on CPU
plan.fft(a, out_cp, cufft.CUFFT_FORWARD)

out_np = numpy.fft.fft(a)  # use NumPy's fft
# np.fft.fft alway returns np.complex128
if dtype is numpy.complex64:
    out_np = out_np.astype(dtype)

# check result
assert np.allclose(out_cp, out_np, rtol=1e-4, atol=1e-7)
```

For this use case, consulting the [cuFFT documentation](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cufft/index.html) on multi-GPU transform is likely useful.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply. Cross checking my understanding:  
Option1 high-level: May I know what bug is there in C2R which does not come for C2C?  It is restricted to only small size FFT fitting only in one GPU. This is not good as it is bound by communication and multi GPU will always be slower as compared to single GPU  
Option2 low-level APIs: From the description, I am assuming that we are using Unified memory. If yes is there any impact that you have measured vs explicit copies. Any reason we could not use non unifiled version at low level API supported by cuFFT

Comment: Let me break up your questions in pieces as I fail to see the connection.
`> May I know what bug is there in C2R which does not come for C2C?`
If you are interested, see https://github.com/cupy/cupy/issues/3757#issuecomment-673783806.

Comment: `> It is restricted to only small size FFT fitting only in one GPU. This is not good as it is bound by communication and multi GPU will always be slower as compared to single GPU` This is correct, communication is the main bottleneck in multi-gpu FFT, so as I said in my post the low-level API is really meant to be the real use-case. If you present a strong use case in CuPy's issue tracker in which you need to use high-level API for multi-GPU FFT, I think the dev team is happy to revisit the decision, although from a developer perspective the API is harder to design.

Comment: `> From the description, I am assuming that we are using Unified memory.`

No, this is not correct. You read it wrong. When I said "NumPy arrays", I really mean data that are allocated by the usual NumPy means and reside in the host (non-pinned, non-managed) memory. The data copy is done using cuFFT's API, so please refer to the multi-GPU example in cuFFT documentation linked in my post. What's done in CuPy's low-level API is an almost 1-to-1 translation of that. It is interesting to explore if managed (unified) memory can be of any help, but I didn't pay much attention during development.